# Counting values to get a matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a variable `age`, 13 variables `x1` to `x13`, and 802 observations in a Stata dataset. `age` has values ranging 1 to 9. `x1` to `x13` have values ranging 1 to 13.

I want to know how to count the number of 1 .. 13 in `x1` to `x13` according to different values of `age`. For example, for `age` 1, in `x1` to `x13`, count the number of 1,2,3,4,...13.

I first change `x1` to `x13` as a matrix by using

```
mkmat x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13, matrix (a)
```

Then, I want to count using the following loop:

```
gen count = 0 
quietly forval i = 1/802 {
    quietly forval j = 1/13 { 
       replace count = count + inrange(a[r'i', x'j'], 0, 1), if age==1
    }
}
```

I failed.

Comment: I am not quite sure what results you strive to obtain. It seems like you want more than one new "count" variable. Could you give an example with simplified data? For your current, drop the "r" and "x" to refer to elements in the matrix. Also maybe check the `egen` command. It has several count functions available.

Comment: for example, for age group 1, there are totally sixteen 1 in matrix a, totally fifteen 2 in matrix a .....totally ten 13 in matrix a.

Answer (score 1):

I am still somewhat uncertain as to what you like to achieve. But if I am understanding you correctly, here is one way to do it.

First, a simple data that has `age` ranging from one to three, and four variables `x1-x4`, each with values of integers ranging between 5 and 7.

```
clear
input age x1 x2 x3 x4
1 5 6 6 6
1 7 5 6 5
2 5 7 6 6
3 5 6 7 7
3 7 6 6 6
end
```

Then we create three count variables (n5, n6 and n7) that counts the number of 5s, 6s, and 7s for each subject across `x1-x4`.

```
forval i=5/7    {
    egen n`i'=anycount(x1 x2 x3 x4),v(`i')
}
```

Below is how the data looks like now. To explain, the first "1" under `n5` indicates that there is only one "5" for the subject across `x1-x4`.

```
     +----------------------------------------+
     | age   x1   x2   x3   x4   n5   n6   n7 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |   1    5    6    6    6    1    3    0 |
  2. |   1    7    5    6    5    2    1    1 |
  3. |   2    5    7    6    6    1    2    1 |
  4. |   3    5    6    7    7    1    1    2 |
  5. |   3    7    6    6    6    0    3    1 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

It sounds to me like your ultimate goal is to have sums calculated separately for each value in age. Assuming this is true, let's create a 3x3 matrix to store such results.

```
mat A=J(3,3,.) // age (1-3) and values (5-7)
mat rown A=age1 age2 age3
mat coln A=value5 value6 value7

forval i=5/7    {
    forval j=1/3    {
        qui su n`i' if age==`j'
        loca k=`i'-4 // the first column for value5
        mat A[`j',`k']=r(sum)
    }
}
```

The matrix looks like this. To explain, the first "3" under `value5` indicates that for all children of the age of 1, the value 5 appears a total of three times across `x1-x4`

```
A[3,3]
      value5  value6  value7
age1       3       4       1
age2       1       2       1
age3       1       4       3
```

Comment: thank you very much. I got value from 1 to 13, and age ranging from 1 to 11. I want to produce the matrix like what you provided in the last step- A [11,13]. I notice that in your example, it has 4 6s for age 1, but in the result, it only shows 1 6. Is there any mistake in your programming? ..i am a beginner in stata. ..thanks again for the help.

Comment: Some changes of course have to be made, but I think the principles in this example should suffice. For creating a larger matrix, change values in the `mat A=J(3,3,.)` line. You can always view what the matrix looks like with `mat list A`. And thanks for catching the mistake. I mixed up the order of rows and columns in the last line. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With Aspen's example, you could do this:

```
gen id = _n 
reshape long x, i(id) 
tab age x
```

Note that your sample code doesn't loop over different ages and there is an incorrect comma in the `count` command. I won't try to fix the code, as there are many more direct methods, one of which is above. `tabulate` has an option to save the table as a matrix.

Here is another solution closer to the original idea. Warning: code not tested.

```
matrix count = J(9, 13, 0) 

forval i = 1/9 { 
    forval j = 1/13 { 
        forval J = 1/13 { 
            qui count if age == `i' & x`J' == `j'   
            matrix count[`i', `j'] = count[`i', `j'] + r(N) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great code. `reshape` is way more efficient than what I had.